# Chrome shortcuts on long press

Tags: chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

I added a shortcut to my home screen through Chrome by selecting the "Add to Home screen option", but unfortunately added a few that do not work (they come up with "page expired" when I tap the shortcut). I deleted those shortcuts, but now I noticed when I long press the Chrome icon on my home screen, those shortcuts all still show up in the app shortcuts list. Is there a way I can delete those? I cannot seem to find a way to manage those long press shortcuts.

Comment: Did not work - went to app settings > Storage > Clear cache, then rebooted. The shortcuts still show up.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either.

Comment: Thanks for the revert--I thought deleting cache of launcher +Chrome should do the trick. I don't know if deleting data off Chrome would help. Could give it a try

Comment: Yea, I'm hesitant to delete things from Chrome other than cache because I don't want to accidentally delete all my bookmarks and saved passwords...

Comment: Last try from my side - Download [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) (free version) run all the cleaning tasks it let's you, reboot and check

Comment: Didn't work either...thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: Sorry...your problem is unique. Hope you get a solution soon